# Adding a variable to an existing matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

so i have a matrix "force1"
i have created a list called birth_binary and I want to add it to force 1 .
how? [image]

[image]

Comment: You say "matrix" but your code says "list".

Comment: 1.) `force1` is not a matrix. 2.) You don't need to initialize variables in R. 3.) Study `help("[")`.

Comment: This looks unntatural. Would you please share your code as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture? You also don't generally need to initialize vectors with `vector()`. Or even at all. You could do `force1$birth_binary = ifelse(force1[[2]] < 45, 1, 0)` to add it directly, skipping intermediate steps. This would not work if `force1` was a matrix, but since we can see it's a `list` it will work.

Comment: @GregorThomas your line of code worked! thank you so much! sorry for saying its a matrix I'm still new to R.

Comment: The distinctions between a `matrix`, a `data.frame` and a `list` are important! You'll get there :)